# PHP wrapper for PhantomJS no ouput

Tags: php, codeigniter, phantomjs

So i'm using: `https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs` a PHP wrapper for Phantom JS. I have followed the instructions and used composer to install the package:

`php composer require jonnyw/php-phantomjs:2.*`

I'm using Codeigniter so I had to declare the use before my class definition:

```
use JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client;
class WebScrape extends CI_Controller { require 'vendor/autoload.php'; ..}
```

Then I used this code:

```
    $client = Client::getInstance();
    $client->setPhantomJs('/var/www/PhantomJS/vendor/bin/');
    $request = $client->getMessageFactory()->createRequest('GET', 'http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php#56144');

    $response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();

    // Send the request
    $client->send($request, $response);    
    echo $response->getStatus();
    if($response->getStatus() === 200) {

        // Dump the requested page content
        echo $response->getContent();
    }
```

I get no errors, but `$response->getStatus();` returns to me 0. I don't know how to debug this since, I have no PHP errors either. Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with this problem do the following:

### Uninstall phantomjs

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove phantomjs
```

### Clean Install

```
cd /usr/local/share
sudo wget https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
sudo tar xjf phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/share/phantomjs
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin/phantomjs
```

Add the following line under `$client = Client::getInstance();`

```
$client->setPhantomJs('/usr/local/share/phantomjs');
```

Now Make sure that `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` precedes `use JonnyW\PhantomJs\Client;`

Should work: